While applying layout in react the error is coming in Fast Refresh in vite
Applayout Code
import React from "react";
import { IoChatbubbles } from "react-icons/io5";
import { CiMail } from "react-icons/ci";

const AppLayout = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex">
            <div className="w-[80px] h-[95vh] bg-gray-800 my-[2.5vh] ml-6 rounded-xl flex flex-col relative items-center">
                <IoChatbubbles className="fill-primary scale-150 my-[30px] " />
                <div className="">
                    <CiMail className="fill-primary"/>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
            < WrappedComponent {...props }/>
            <div>Footer</div>
        </ div>
        );
};

export default AppLayout;

Home.jsx Code:-
import React from 'react'
import AppLayout from '../layout/AppLayout'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       My name is Akash
    </div>
  )
}

export default AppLayout(Home);

The error is coming in FastRefresh:-
9:21:50 AM [vite] hmr invalidate /src/pages/Home.jsx Could not Fast Refresh. Learn more at https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#consistent-components-exports
9:21:50 AM [vite] hmr update /src/index.css, /src/App.jsx

I tried to read https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#consistent-components-exports but donot get any solution from this doc. please help
